# Error in Sonar Plugin Integration With Eclipse 3.7 Indigo

Tags: eclipse-indigo

I'm trying to install the sonar plug in for `Eclipse 3.6 Indigo`.

Below is the way I have followed.

> ```
> Help-> Install New Software-> and the following url to find the plugin.
> "http://dist.sonar-ide.codehaus.org/eclipse/"
> ```

But it is showing pending for some time and after that it was displaying the below error.

**Error:**

```
 Unable to read repository at http://dist.sonar-ide.codehaus.org/eclipse/content.xml.
 Socket closed

 Unable to connect to repository  Connection timed out: connect
```

Please help me how to proceed and do the needful.

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Comment: Bhaskar, this is issue with network connectivity from within Eclipse. Go to Preferences--> Network --> Connections and configure appropriate proxy (Similar to one you configure for browser). And please close this question as too localized.

Comment: Thank you so much vishal. I have installed the plugins. now I have one more question. After installing sonar plugins in eclipse, is it required to install sonar Qube server or SonarQube Runner in my machine??

Comment: AFAIK, yes the Sonar plugin only does data push, you will need a separate Sonar Server with MySQL DB, but can't say with gurantee

Comment: Hi, How to mark the question as answered

Comment: Added answer, you can mark that as correct

Answer (score 1):

configuring hostname in eclipse solved my problem

Go to Preferences--> Network --> Connections and configure appropriate proxy (Similar to one you configure for browser). Thank you Vishal

Answer (score 0):

This is issue with network connectivity from within Eclipse. Go to Preferences--> Network --> Connections and configure appropriate proxy (Similar to one you configure for browser). And please close this question as too localized

To answer "After installing sonar plugins in eclipse, is it required to install sonar Qube server or SonarQube Runner in my machine??"

AFAIK, yes the Sonar plugin only does data push, you will need a separate Sonar Server with MySQL DB, but can't say with gurantee